# Specify query hints for SimpleJpaRepository find methods

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

## Goal

I'm implementing a custom base repository with the goal of being able to specify attribute nodes of entity graphs by method argument instead of method annotation. So instead of having annotated methods like

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = ["enrollments"])
fun findByIdFetchingEnrollments(id: Long): Optional<Student>
```

in my repositories, I just have a base repository with a method like

```
fun findById(id: ID, vararg attributeNodes: String): Optional<T>
```

which gives a lot of flexibility because with only one method I can, for example, call

```
studentRepository.findById(1L, "enrollments") 
// or
studentRepository.findById(1L, "favouriteSubjects", "favouriteTeachers")
// and others...
```

where `"enrollments"`, `"favouriteSubjects"`, and `"favouriteTeachers"` are lazy-fetch entity fields by default but sometimes are required to be fetched eagerly (to avoid `LazyInitializationException`)

## What I have

Those are my classes:

```
// Base repository interface. All my repositories will extend this interface

@NoRepositoryBean
interface Repository<T, ID> : JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    fun findById(id: ID, vararg attributeNodes: String): Optional<T>
    
    // other find methods

}
```

```
// Custom base class. Inherits SimpleJpaRepository

class RepositoryImpl<T, ID>(
        val entityInformation: JpaEntityInformation<T, Any?>,
        val em: EntityManager
) : SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>(entityInformation, em), Repository<T,ID> {

    // This is basically a copy-paste of SimpleJpaRepository findById method implementation... 
    override fun findById(id: ID, vararg attributeNodes: String): Optional<T> {
    
        Assert.notNull(id, "The given id must not be null!")

        /*
        Because 'repositoryMethodMetadata!!.queryHints' is read-only, I have to create a new Map,
        put all the queryHints entries in it and put the 'javax.persistence.loadgraph' hint.
         */

        val graph = em.createEntityGraph(entityInformation.javaType)
        graph.addAttributeNodes(*attributeNodes)

        val hints: MutableMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()
        hints.putAll(repositoryMethodMetadata!!.queryHints)

        hints["javax.persistence.loadgraph"] = graph

        if (repositoryMethodMetadata == null) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(em.find(domainClass, id, hints))
        }

        val type = repositoryMethodMetadata!!.lockModeType

        return Optional.ofNullable(
                if (type == null) em.find(domainClass, id, hints)
                else em.find(domainClass, id, type, hints)
        )
    }

    /* 
    In order to implement the other find methods the same kind of copy-paste implementations
    needs to be done, which shouldn't be necessary but I'm not seeing how.
    */

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        "com.domain.project.repository",
        repositoryBaseClass = RepositoryImpl::class)
class ApplicationConfiguration
```

## Problem

**The problem is that I'm not seeing a simple way of adding the javax.persistence.loadgraph hint to the query hints that SimpleJpaRepository pass to EnitityManager.find.**

I think the best way to solve this would be override the SimpleJpaRepository [`getQueryHints()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#getQueryHints--)  method which is used by all *find* methods in `SimpleJpaRepository`. Then my code in `RepositoryImpl` would become much simpler (override all *find* methods, and for each just add the hint and call super method). But I can't override it because `QueryHints` class is package-private.

If SimpleJpaRepository [`metadata`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#getRepositoryMethodMetadata--) property were mutable, I could also add to it query hints (which in turn are considered in `getQueryHints()` method), but all its properties are read-only and I think sometimes `metadata` is null (not sure on this but it is marked as `@Nullable`).